# How do I Entity Framework Core relation table models?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

When using the Entity Framework Core 7 Scaffold, only the `User`, `Permission` and `Group` models are generated.

I have 3 independent tables:

- User
- Permission
- Group

And 2 relation tables:

- GroupPermission
- UserGroup

How do I allow the generation of those remaining tables?

NOTE: the `ICollection` reference for the relationship tables is generated in the model.

NOTE2: The reason I asked this question is why I'm having trouble using linq to Entity Framework when relating them with Join.

Ex:

```
from u in _context.User 
join gui in _context.gu
```

cannot be assigned, since the model was not generated

Comment: Are the `GroupPermission` and `UserGroup` tables there to implement _many-to-many_ relationships? EF models them directly in the models to the two tables in the relationships. For example `User` should have a `Groups` property while `Group` should have a `Users` property

Comment: Exactly, the problem is that as the model is not generated, I don't know how to generate a linq expression to get from the user to their permissions.

The property was generated...

User -> GroupUser -> Group -> PermissionGroups -> Permission

Would there be any way to do this?

Comment: If you want to get `Permission` from `User`, you can use linq query like this :

`_context.User.Include(u => u.Group).ThenInclude(k => k.Permission);`

Comment: Please turn this into a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get `Permission` from `User`, you can use query like this :

```
var user = _context.User.Include(u => u.Group).ThenInclude(k => k.Permission);
```

And then using linq like this :

```
var ListOfPermission = user.Group.SelectMany(k => k.Permission);
```

Or if you prefer using query syntax , here is the code :

```
var ListOfPermission = from g in user.Groups
                           from permission in g.Permissions
                  select permission;
```